# Sending an Opencv feature descriptor from android device to JAVA server

Tags: android, json, opencv, client-server, transmission

I want to compare data transmission cost of diffrent feature descriptors provided by the `Opencv4Android` package.

After Feature extraction the descriptor is represented by the `OPENCV Mat Object`

My question now is how to send this object to server via mobile network connection.

It is a possible to use JSON ?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html

Comment: @William YAML is not included in the official opencv package for Android

Comment: Then do it manually. First print a header (channels,type,width,height) and then print the pixels in a way you desire.

Comment: Hi nawara, did you find any solution for your question ? i am trying to send the features in JSON format.